# Can miff pipe be used more than once in imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

cmd1:   convert -background none -fill "rgb(254,253,185)"   -strokewidth 1 -stroke "rgb(6,3,36)"  -font ./ss.ttf  -pointsize 48  -kerning -7  label:'hello professor' -trim -gravity center zq1.png -append  +repage label.png && convert ./giftemp/par.gif  (  +clone )  -dispose previous -delay 0   -page +10+235 label.png -page +10+190 label.png -page +10+170 label.png -delay 200  -page +10+142 label.png -loop 0 ./gif/end.gif

I want to replace "label.png" in cmd1  with miff:- pipe  :

cmd2:  convert -background none -fill "rgb(254,253,185)"   -strokewidth 1 -stroke "rgb(6,3,36)"  -font ./ss.ttf  -pointsize 48  -kerning -7  label:'hello professor' -trim -gravity center zq1.png -append  +repage miff:-| convert ./giftemp/par.gif  (  +clone )  -dispose previous -delay 0   -page +10+235 label.png -page +10+190 -  -page +10+170 - -delay 200  -page +10+142 -  -loop 0 ./gif/end.gif

But it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IM reads the input pipe "-" only once, but you can work it like this...

Start your second command by reading that pipe with "-" and writing it into a memory register like "mpr:piped". Then delete it from the list and continue your second command using the memory register "mpr:piped" wherever you wanted to read from the pipe.

```
convert label:'hello' miff:- | convert - \
   -write mpr:piped -delete 0--1 \
   input1.png mpr:piped input2.png mpr:piped +append output.png
```